# Spy and callThrough with Angular ESLint

Tags: jestjs, jasmine, ts-jest

I have an old Angular application that I'm upgrading to Angular 12, replacing TSLint with ESLint and rewriting unit tests. I've already done most of the work but one test doesn't work.

```
spyOn(productPriceService, 'calculate').and.callThrough()
```

I configured the angular-eslint (following the official guideline: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint) and also installed the eslint-plugin-jest plugin :

```
{
    "plugins": ["jest"],
    "env": {
        "jest/globals": true
    }
}
```

So now I can spy the method via:

```
jest.spyOn(productPriceService, 'calculate')
```

But then I cannot do and.callThrough because these methods are in a different namespace - jasmine instead of jest.

```
Property 'and' does not exist on type 'SpyInstance<void, []>'.
```

Could someone help me out how I can spy the method and do callThrough? I already tried several ways but none of them worked. Here are the list of installed dev dependencies:

```
"@angular-builders/jest": "^12.1.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "12.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.0",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.23.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.23.0",
"eslint": "^7.26.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
"eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
"husky": "^7.0.0",
"jest": "^27.0.6",
"jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^2.0.0",
"jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
"jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
"jest-marbles": "^2.5.1",
"jest-preset-angular": "^9.0.4",
"lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
"prettier": "^2.3.2",
"stylelint": "^13.13.1",
"stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
"stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
"stylelint-scss": "^3.19.0",
"ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
"ts-node": "^10.0.0",
"typescript": "~4.3.2",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2"
```

Comment: `jest.spyOn` is **not** the same thing as Jasmine's (which you shouldn't have been using, as it was never part of Jest's public API). See https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname - it calls through by default.